# Synchronization of SQLITE and MYSQL database in remote location

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, synchronization

I created a sample application using SQLite database. Now I need to synchronize this database with MYSQL database which is located in remote system. Please help me with some simple code on this.

Comment: check 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075765/how-to-sync-sqlite-to-mysql